# Set a flag for duplicates in a sql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some field of duplicate value. I can't delete those duplicates beacause I don't know which ones are correct, so i want to identify all records that have possible duplicates for same values and  set in a column the id of the possible duplicates.
This is an example test table:

```
id col1 col2
---------------- 
1  aaa  aaa
2  baa  bbb
3  abc  ccc
4  cde  aaa
5  baa  bbb
6  aaa  aaa
```

and want to achieve the following result finding duplicates in col2:

```
id col1 col2 dup
---------------- 
1  aaa  aaa  4,6 
2  baa  bbb  5
3  abc  ccc
4  cde  aaa  6,1
5  baa  bbb  2
6  aaa  aaa  1,4
```

So for more than one duplicate it must report a comma separated list of duplicate found.
I have an sql statement to identify those duplicates but no idea how to set an update query:

```
 select distinct l.* from table l
 inner join table r on l.id != r.id and l.col2 = r.col2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
mysql> select id, col1, col2, (select group_concat(id) from bubu q where q.col2=a.col2 and q.id <> a.id group by q.col2) as dup from bubu a;
+----+------+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 | dup  |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | aaa  | aaa  | 4,6  |
|  2 | baa  | bbb  | 5    |
|  3 | abc  | ccc  | NULL |
|  4 | cde  | aaa  | 1,6  |
|  5 | baa  | bbb  | 2    |
|  6 | aaa  | aaa  | 1,4  |
+----+------+------+------+
```

To update the original table, it looks like you need to create a temporary table first:

```
create table tmp as select id, (select group_concat(id) from bubu q where q.col2=a.col2 
and q.id <> a.id group by q.col2) as dup from bubu a;

update bubu a set dup = (select dup from tmp where tmp.id=a.id);
```

If your table is large, it's probably helpful to create an index on `tmp.id` before updating (but haven't tested).